# Passing data from my razor view to my js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, razor

I'm searching for the best way to **pass data from my razor view to my js file**. For example, lets say we have a jquery dialog configured in the js file. For buttons text on this dialog, I would like to localize it (through resource files FR/NL/UK). The translations are available with @UserResource.ButtonDelete + @UserResource.ButtonCancel

Below are the different solutions I see:

1. Using the nice [RazorJS](http://djsolid.net/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files) nuget package to allows razor code inside my javascript file. It works pretty well. But the question is: **is it a bad practice to compile js files in order to use razor syntax inside the scripts?**
2. Declaring global variables in the js script file and assign value from the view like this:

In the view:

```
<script>
        var labelButtonDelete = @UserResource.ButtonDelete;
</script>
```

In the js file:

```
alert('The text for my button is ' + labelButtonDelete);
```

What is the best way to pass data from razor to js file? Do you have another alternative?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using something like your second approach for some time without any issues. The only difference is that I'm using a [singleton](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript) in my JS file to avoid polluting the global javascript namespace.

But if you will be doing more serious client side stuff, your Javascript code will follow a more object oriented structure, and from there you almost automatically get a single initialization/constructor path where you can pass your localized values.

That RazorJS looks nice, but I'm not sure if I'm comfortable mixing Javascript with Razor. Might do it for a small project, but I can see it becoming really messy if you have lots of Javascript files.

After all, I still consider the resources/localization code to be related to the view. The Javascript should only implement functionality in my opinion.