# Using MVC resource in Jquery - function stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Jquery function in MVC View that check if at least one checkbox is clicked. Function is working properly if I use hardcoded string. But when I add 
@Resources.myString into, it stops working, I can't figure out why

```
    $('.form-horizontal').on('submit', function (e) {
        if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert("This is working");
            alert(@Resources.myString); //with this the function is not working anymore

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I need to add the the string for multilingual purpose.
I tried diferent aproches

```
alert(@Resources.myString);
alert(@Html.Raw(Resources.myString))
var aaa = { @Html.Raw(Resources.myString)} //and calling the aaa
```

I think I am missing some basic knowlage of how this should work together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During page rendering, `@Resources.myString` will be injected as is in the code. For instance, if `myString == "abc";`, you'll end up with `alert(abc);` which is not what you want.

Just try to enclose your string in quotes:

```
alert("@Resources.myString");
```

As an aside, putting Razor code in Javascript logic is usually considered bad practice, as it prevents you from putting Javascript code in separate files (and therefore caching), and makes the code less readable.

Take a look as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9616264/1679537) and the provided answer which gives a simple way to deal with that.

Comment: working! thank you (have to wait 7min to click answered)

Answer (score 0):

As ASP.NET dynamically generates HTML, CSS, JS code, the best way to find the error is to read the generated sources (`Ctrl + U` in most modern browsers).

You will see that your code

```
alert(@Resources.myString);
```

produces

```
alert(yourStringContent);
```

and should result in a console error `yourStringContent is not defined`.

You need to use quotes as you are working with a JavaScript string:

```
alert('@Resources.myString');
```

It will produce a correct JavaScript code like:

```
alert('yourStringContent');
```